# Bash script doesn't evaluate variable in filename

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script which creates a backup of my folder. It should name the tar gz file using a version number but it doesn't:

```
#!/bin/bash

ver='1.2.3'
tar czf $ver_myfolder.tar.gz .
```

Expected output:

> 1.2.3_myfolder.tar.gz

Actual output:

> _myfolder.tar.gz

If I append the variable like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ver='1.2.3'
tar czf myfolder-$ver.tar.gz .
```

It works

Comment: It can't find the variable named `$ver_myfolder`

Comment: Are you sure your actual output is `_myfolder.tar.gz`? I would have expected it to be `.tar.gz` (see also the replies for the why). Try `ls -a` to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `${var}` here since you are appending underscore after it which is considered a valid character for variable names. Due to that fact shell doesn't know whether you're expanding variable name `$ver` or `$ver_myfolder`:

```
ver='1.2.3'
tar czf "${ver}_myfolder.tar.gz" .
```

Since `$ver_myfolder` is unset, you get an empty value.

Comment: ok now I got it, thanks

Comment: Other than using `${var}` format, it is also recommended to quote the value to avoid unexpected expansion behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Because the underscore is a valid character for a variable name, you should use braces to explicitly specify the range of your variable:

```
${ver}_myfolder.tar.gz
 ^   ^
```

Without braces, Bash will actually try to parse

```
${ver_myfolder}.tar.gz
```

For your edited question, it is because the dot is *not* a valid character for a variable name, so Bash will not attempt to parse the dot into the name lookup. Even if you put it into braces, a variable name containing a dot is still invalid:

```
$ echo ${ver.}
bash: ${ver.}: bad substitution
$ ver.=1.2.3
ver.=1.2.3: command not found
```

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini What about accepting my answer?